# building simple web app to download file in node js

Tags: node.js, express, download

I am using the below code to download pdf files but a download popup is not rendering. Why?

```
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=document.pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
  res.download(__dirname + '\\uploads\\document.pdf');
```

The above code is what I am using but the response is not expected.

Comment: Are you getting any response or error? Send more information about it.

Comment: in the response not readable text are comming and no error is found